# what's my application package name in android?

Tags: java, android, manifest

I'm writing an android application.

It has some packages under `src`.

how can I figure out which of them is my application package?

I want to add C@DM permissions:

```
<permission android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

how will my `YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME` change if I create a custom `MyApplication extends Application` class?

Comment: The folder structure where you have added a class. normally this will be com.companyname.productname

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your application name is actually defined in the AndroidManifest.xml, in its first lines. Ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yourcompany.appname"
    android:versionCode="66"
    android:versionName="0.57" >
```

note the package="com.yourcompany.appname" - this is your package definition.

Other places which contain your package name can be resources, class paths, packages and much more. But all of them should be aligned according to the manifest because that what the package manager reads.

Comment: Extending Application or not has no effect on your package or the package name. Its optional.

Comment: Maybe you could have provided the location for the AndroidManifest.xml? I don't have any such file anywhere in my app folder. Downvoted.

Comment: If you are using Gradle build system then read this instead http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. First click on project option
2. Go to android
3. Click on app option under android after that click on java option
4. after that application package name will appear

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Newer Android Studio using Gradle do not have "package name" nor is it mentioned in "AndroidManifest.xml".

Please find instead the "applicationId" inside the "build.gradle.kts" file, at module level not project level.

I.e.:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapp"
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/build/configure-app-module

Quote:

> the applicationId is automatically assigned the package name you chose during setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in MainActivity.kt and ManinApplication.kt file at the starting line of the code with other imports.

Answer (score -2):

inside android/build.gradle folder applicationId

[SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUIeG.png)